# Parsing json into a nested ArrayList in libgdx

Tags: java, json, libgdx

I was using Jackson for all my json serialisation and deserialisation, but I'm trying to get my game working with GWT now so I'm moving over to the libgdx json parsing libraries.

Everything seems ok so far except this

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<HighScoreEntry>> high_scores =
              new HashMap<String, ArrayList<HighScoreEntry>>();
```

The ArrayList within the hashmap is being created as a array of JsonValue rather than an array of HighScoreEntry.

Can someone explain how I work around this? I know about json.setElementType(); but can't see how to use it in this instance. I'm playing with writing custom serialisation, but again, I can't work out how to extract exactly what I need.

I'm guessing in a custom serialiser I can use

```
    json.readFields(this, jsonData);
```

to populate everything and then correct the erroneous data afterwards.

HighScoreEntry class (without methods):

```
public class HighScoreEntry implements Comparable<HighScoreEntry>, java.io.Serializable {
    public long id;
    public int score;
    public String language = "en";
    public String data;
    public String name;

    public boolean current;
}
```

[image]

Pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Provide more information on HighScoreEntry class please

Comment: @Tukajo Added HighScoreEntry.

Comment: What is telling you that it is a `JsonValue` and not a `HighScoreEntry`?

Comment: @Tukajo Inspecting at runtime. See the image I just added.

Comment: I don't think that is referring to the `ArrayList`? I believe the entry above it is? under `Value` in your image. of type `Array`

Comment: Oh sorry I misread your question a bit. One moment.

Comment: @Tukajo I've just been playing with the libgdx Array type too. Whether it's an Array or ArrayList I have the same problem. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you try creating a new object type and substituting it into that hashmap and see what happens?

Comment: @Tukajo I've already tried that I'm afraid. Exactly the same problem. It seems if there are generics anywhere in the object hierarchy this problem occurs.

Comment: are you willing to provide me a temporary pastebin of more code to look over?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80306/discussion-between-will-calderwood-and-tukajo).

Answer (score 0):

I've worked something out, but I feel like there must be a better way. If anyone else has any ideas then please post them.

Adding a custom reader I can correct the corrupted high scores and convert them into instances of HighScoreEntry objects.

```
@Override
public void read(Json json, JsonValue jsonData) {
    // Read all the fields
    json.readFields(this, jsonData);

    // replace high scores
    HighScoreHashMapJsonValue screwedUpHashMap = json.readValue(HighScoreHashMapJsonValue.class, jsonData.get("high_scores"));
    HashMap<String, Array<HighScoreEntry>> newHighScores = new HashMap<String, Array<HighScoreEntry>>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Array<JsonValue>> entry : screwedUpHashMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Array<JsonValue> jsonValueHighScores = entry.getValue();

        Array<HighScoreEntry> highScoreArray = new Array<HighScoreEntry>();
        newHighScores.put(key, highScoreArray);
        for (JsonValue highScore : jsonValueHighScores) {
            highScoreArray.add(json.readValue(HighScoreEntry.class, highScore));
        }
    }

    high_scores = newHighScores;
}

public static class HighScoreHashMapJsonValue extends HashMap<String, Array<JsonValue>> {

}
```